# Return Value in Completion of Function

Tags: ios, swift, completion

I have built my own swift framework for running queries on a MySQL database. I am currently developing a chat application in which I need to display an avatar image for each user who is currently chatting.

I am retrieving the user's profile picture URL from my database and then I need to return a `UIImage` once I get the profile picture URL. I get the error `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`. Is there a way to make this easier or bypass this error?

This is my full code:

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {

    let currentMessage = self.messages[indexPath.row]

    if (currentMessage.senderId == self.senderId) {
        // Current User sent message

        var imageURL: NSURL!

        ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.complexQuery("SELECT profile_picture FROM users WHERE username='\(self.senderId)' ", completion: { (result) in
            if let results = result as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for result in results {
                    if let profilePictureURL = result["profile_picture"] {
                        print(profilePictureURL)

                        imageURL = profilePictureURL as! NSURL
                        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                        // ERROR HERE (line below)
                        return JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(image, diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    } else {

        var imageURL: NSURL!

        ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.complexQuery("SELECT profile_picture FROM users WHERE username='\(currentMessage.senderId)' ", completion: { (result) in
            if let results = result as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for result in results {
                    if let profilePictureURL = result["profile_picture"] {
                        print(profilePictureURL)

                        imageURL = profilePictureURL as! NSURL
                        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                        // ERROR HERE (line below)
                        return JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(image, diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(UIImage(data: (NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL))!), diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))     }

Comment: What does the above return?

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson I am using the JSQMessageViewController library to display my chat messages in my view controller. It returns a JSQMessagesAvatarImage (basically an image from the URL returned by the query).

Comment: Ok cool, cheers for the speedy response :)

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson I just updated my code to make it easier to understand the return statement. And no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.complexQuery is an asynchronous function, so the main thread will continue after calling it, there will be nothing left in this context to receive what will be returned 
so, do what ever you want with the image in the callback function "completion"
for example, you may get a reference of your UIImageView and set it's image when you get it, but you need to use another data source delegate method

```
collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)
```

Something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(YOUR_ID,
                               forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourOwnCell
        ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.complexQuery("SELECT profile_picture FROM users WHERE username='\(currentMessage.senderId)' ", completion: { (result) in
            if let results = result as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for result in results {
                    if let profilePictureURL = result["profile_picture"] {
                        print(profilePictureURL)

                        imageURL = profilePictureURL as! NSURL
                        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                        // Assuming avatarImageWithImage is returning UIImageView
                        cell.imageView = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(image, diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: That is what I am doing however it is not letting me return the image in the callback function.

Comment: The callback function aren't being called by your code, but with the code inside "complexQuery" function

Comment: I just started using the JSQMessage library and I don't know how to implement this function alongside the library...

Comment: it's not a JSQMessage issue here, it's the step before, the complexQuery, because it's async. but wait a moment, you have only two avatars (or multiple if it's group chat) but the point is you are making the query over and over again, and it will always return the same image (for a user) so you may need to move your query some where else

Comment: Wow I feel really stupid for not seeing this before... I got this to work thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

What you try isn't how asynchronous functions work. It's not how they *could* work. The whole point of an asynchronous call is that your app can continue running while the asynchronous call continues running in the background. Your complexQuery function returns immediately so that you can continue.

Instead of this function *returning* the value that you want, your completion code must deposit the value in the right place.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried to do this by instead setting my `imageURL` variable inside the completion code. I placed the return statement after the `complexQuery` function however I always get the error that `imageURL` is nil. I am pretty new to completions so sorry if I sound stupid right now...

Comment: The reason for that is the rest of your code runs while the asynchronous call is waiting for a response. So the function finishes before the block in completion runs

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply... @AMTourky gave a solution. Instead of retrieving the profile picture of each user for EACH post I would retrieve them right when the application runs then add them to each post. This works better because there are only two users in the chat so it would also be inefficient to load the image each time a post is loaded. Thanks for the help :)